# not able to find multi select dropdown, only h:selectManyListbox is present

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am looking for a dropdown something like this

[image]

I am not able to find any component that suits my need.Only following component is present, but this component is not fulfilling my needs as the data is not showing like a dropdown with multi-select capabilites in it.

```
                    <h:selectManyListbox id="option">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{supportData.states}" />
                </h:selectManyListbox>
```

Please suggest , what shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

you can use SelectCheckboxMenu in primefaces

Answer (score 0):

The primefaces will help you and the showcase is here.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectCheckboxMenu.jsf